# Is there any way to link my native code against prebuilt shared libraries without using the experimental Android Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project that uses the non-experimental version of the Android Gradle plugin (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3). I have some native code that I build into a shared library libnative.so.

The problem is that now I want to link libnative.so against a prebuilt library. Let's call this file libfoo.so. If I set the jniLibs.srcDir to the folder containing libfoo.so for the different ABIs I see that it gets bundled into my APK.

However I don't understand how I am supposed to link against it successfully. If I add "foo" to ldLibs I get a linker error saying that it can't find the library. This is probably because the folder containing libfoo.so is not included as a search path to the linker.

How am I supposed to do this? Is it simply not possible without switching to the experimental gradle plugin?

This is my gradle file. I stripped away the part that probably is irrelevant for this problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "0.0.11"
        def foodir = "${project.buildDir}/../../foo"
        ndk {
            moduleName "native"
            ldLibs "foo"
            stl "gnustl_static"
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ["${foodir}"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```